# Простой способ предсказания следующего значения (марковский предиктор, "муравьиный" алгоритм, рекурсия Левинсона-Дарбина)

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Имеется числовой ряд, программно некоторый массив длины `N`. Необходим самый простой алгоритм предсказания следующего значения `N+1`, основанный на всех предыдущих значениях. Подскажите пожалуйста такой.

Мой ряд представлен **случайными** положительными дробными числами. В общем любые несложные идеи хотелось бы рассмотреть.

**UPD**::*откуда берутся числа?*

Есть 50 равноудаленных приемо-передатчиков (ПП), не важно как, но любой может связаться с любым ([полносвязная топология](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Полносвязная_топология)). Есть абстрактные источник и приемник (которые тоже могут связаться с любым из ПП). Связь между источником и приемником **всегда** устанавливается через 5 ПП (источник и приемник естественно не учитываются). В один момент времени, например раз в сутки, связь (маршрут/путь) переформировывается по некоторым, для нас неизвестным, случайным (именно случайным, так как, например, некоторые ПП в данный момент времени недостижимы по какой-то причине) законам. Необходимо предсказать, какой путь (или 6-10 других вариантов путей) будет выбран следующим основываясь лишь на знании предыдущих выборов системы.

Много различных алгоритмов я уже перепробовал. Так как нету статистической зависимости между двумя различными выборами путей (а если и есть, то ее сложно определить, **я даже боюсь утверждать, что смена пути происходит по, например, нормальному распределению вероятности**, но, думаю, что можно предположить это для данной задачи), вот я и пытаюсь теперь аппроксимировать на основе "весов" маршрутов (произведения "весов" каждой пары ПП, извлекаемых из матрицы переходов (веса определены на пересечении строки и столбца: *переход из i-го ПП в j-й*), построенной по похожему принципу, описанному [[@northerner](/users/6536/northerner)](/users/6536/northerner), но более упрощенному).

---

Так как веса путей вида |`1,2,3,4,5` | `1,3,2,4,5` | `5,4,3,2,1`|, равны, нехитрые рассчеты дают чуть больше 2млн. возможных маршрутов. Для каждого из них я вычисляю вес (по матрице). Аналогично мы можем посчитать вес маршрута для каждого предыдущего **уже выбранного системой** маршрута (промежуток - год, для каждого дня в году). Предсказывая поведение значения веса, мы из двух миллионов выберем 6-10 вариантов наиболее схожих с нашим предсказанным значением.

На данный момент я дошел лишь до того, что предположив нормальное распределение мы можем выделить наиболее редко встречающиеся пары в матрице переходов. Например, есть пары, которых за год еще ни разу не встречалось (у которых в матрице переходов на пересечении - нуль их приходится заменять так как они портят картину, как я считаю). Тем не менее эти пары не начинают пока появляться чаще остальных.

---

Если есть альтернативные идеи/методы предсказания маршрутов, буду рад. Если есть идеи, как установить зависимость между сменами маршрутов, распределение и другие характеристики, тоже буду рад.

Comment: Если следующее значение основано на предыдущих, то это уже случайный процесс какой-то получается. Все равно это общие слова, давайте больше конретики.

Comment: А какая еще конкретика нужна?

Comment: Сходимость у ряда какая?

Comment: @karmadro4, не совсем уверен, что мои случайные значения можно исследовать на сходимость.

Comment: @Dex, может быть что-то известно о "природе" этих чисел. Откуда они вообще берутся ?

Если их вводит человек, которого *попросили вводить случайные числа*, то на самом деле **ряд не случаен**.

Comment: @avp, см. UPD.

Comment: @Dex, IMHO для Вашего случая ответ @northerner подходит. 

Вроде, по науке, у Вас система со случайными переходами между ее состояниями (где-то когда-то о чем-то  подобном читал).

Только вот вероятности перехода скорее всего нормальному распределению не соответствуют. На самом деле выбор маршрута наверняка не случаен, а является результатом работы неизвестного нам алгоритма оптимизации загрузки сети передачи данных.

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что для решения таких задач существуют нейронные сети. Пытаетесь взломать чью-то сеть?

Comment: Взломать ничего не пытаемся, скорее оптимизировать кое-что.

Я тоже думал о нейронных сетях, только вот как-то сложность реализации меня пугает. Да и проблем будет дофига, начиная с обучения и заканчивая результатами

Comment: @Dex, а если нарисовать график этих весов по 300 точкам и просто глазами посмотреть, то появляется ощущение, что некоторые кусочки повторяются ? 

Конечно, если глаз не видит это не значит, что повторяемости нет. А может быть сразу увидите какие-нибудь  характерные особенности.

Comment: Фильтр Калмана

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно попробовать построить примерный вариационный ряд и создать новое число как случайную величину, распределенную так же.

То есть разбить множество возможных значений `[0; 1]` на `n` промежутков (скажем, на 10), подсчитать, сколько значений попадает в каждый и создать случайную величину, у которой такое же распределение вероятностей.

Comment: Тоже отличная идея! Спасибо.

Comment: Если числа случайные, то это похоже единственный подходящий метод.

Answer (score 6):

Выбор предиктора очень сильно зависит от специфики последовательности. Если количество разных чисел, которые могут встретиться в последовательности невелико, предлагаю простой марковский предиктор.

Будем считать, что элементы последовательности принимают значения от 1 до N (иначе их можно перенумеровать и будет так).

Назовем возможные значения элемнтов состояниями. Пусть мощность множества состояний (количество разных значений) равна K. Определим матрицу P размером KxK и два одномерных массива R и C размером K. Получив очередной элемент последовательности X(N), увеличиваем на единицу значения P(X(N - 1), X(N)), R(X(N - 1)) и C(X(N)). Таким образом постепенно накапливаются значения: P(I, J) - количество переходов из I в J, R(I) - количество уходов из I, C(J) - количество приходов в J. P(I, J) / R(I) - оценка вероятности (частота), находясь в I перейти в J.

Накопив достаточное количество переходов, можно начать "предсказывать": пусть мы находимся в состоянии Z. Разыгрываем случайную величину, равномерно распределенную в [0, 1]. Идем по строке Z слева направо, вычитая P(Z, J) / R(Z). Как только получаем нуль или меньше, стобец, в котором находимся и есть ожидаемый элемент.

Метод хорошо работает при следующих ограничениях:

1. число состояний действительно невелико;
2. процесс стационарен (однороден по времени), то есть, если где-то в начале последовательности из 15 всегда переходили в 42, а в оставшейся части - ни разу, смысла использовать метод нет;
3. следующий элемент существенно зависит от текущего (и гораздо менее - от совсем старых);
4. вероятности перехода распределены достаточно неравномерно (в противном случае имеем белый шум и никакой предиктор ничего не даст).

В описанном алгоритме C(J) оказались не нужны, но иногда требуются, поэтому оставлю и их.

Comment: Отличный алгоритм, правда для другой подзадачи, благодарствую в особой форме награды.

Comment: @Dex, Вы только перепроверьте, пишу больной, немного туго соображаю.

Comment: @northerner, у меня почти так же было уже реализовано, за исключением кое-каких важных мелочей, никак не мог найти.

Answer (score 6):

**UPD**

Один из лучших прогностических методов - авторегрессионный. Во всяком случае, периодические всплески он выловит.

### Модель сигнала

В основе метода - модель авторегрессии (АР) порядка `k` для выборки `i = 0, 1, ..., n-1`:

**x<sub>i</sub>+f<sub>0</sub>x<sub>i-1</sub> + f<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i-2</sub> + f<sub>2</sub>x<sub>i-3</sub> + ... + f<sub>k-1</sub>x<sub>i-k</sub> = 0, где i=k, k+1,..., n-1.**

Порядок модели должен примерно соответствовать сложности сигнала.

### Тёплицева симметрия

Согласно методу наименьших квадратов, следует минимизировать невязку:
**EPS = < (x<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>0</sub>x<sub>i-1</sub> + f<sub>1</sub>x<sub>i-2</sub> + f<sub>2</sub>x<sub>i-3</sub> + ... + f<sub>k</sub>x<sub>i-k</sub>)<sup>2</sup> > <sub>i = k..n-1</sub>,**
для чего следует приравнять к нулю частные производные от невязки по коэффициентам авторегрессии `f<sub>s</sub>` для `s=0..k-1`.
Это приводит к следующей системе уравнений специального вида:

**a<sub>0</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>k-2</sub>f<sub>k-2</sub> + a<sub>k-1</sub>f<sub>k-1</sub> = -a<sub>1</sub>,**
**a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>k-3</sub>f<sub>k-2</sub> + a<sub>k-2</sub>f<sub>k-1</sub> = -a<sub>2</sub>,**
**a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>k-4</sub>f<sub>k-2</sub> + a<sub>k-3</sub>f<sub>k-1</sub> = -a<sub>3</sub>,**
**...**
**a<sub>k-2</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>k-3</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>k-4</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>0</sub>f<sub>k-2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>k-1</sub> = -a<sub>k-1</sub>,**
**a<sub>k-1</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>k-2</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>k-3</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>k-2</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>f<sub>k-1</sub> = -a<sub>k</sub>,**

где **a** - автокорреляционная функция (АКФ).

Первая особенность - вид матрицы в левой части, когда совпадают коэффициенты на главной диагонали и все коэффициенты на диагоналях, равноотстоящих от главной. Матрицы с симметрией такого вида называются тёплицевыми, и к ним применим алгоритм Левинсона.

Вторая особенность - в том, что столбец свободных членов сформирован из  элементов той же матрицы **a,** и к такой системе применим алгоритм [Левинсона-Дарбина](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion).

Третья особенность - что на самом деле тёплицевой данная матрица является лишь приблизительно. Например, для модели второго порядка точный вид уравнений такой:

**< x<sub>i-1</sub><sup>2</sup> > f<sub>0</sub> + < x<sub>i-1</sub>x<sub>i-2</sub> > f<sub>1</sub> = < x<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i-1</sub> >,**
 **< x<sub>i-1</sub>x<sub>i-2</sub> > f<sub>0</sub> + < x<sub>i-2</sub><sup>2</sup> > f<sub>1</sub> = < x<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i-2</sub> >,**
где индекс **i** в каждой сумме вида **< u<sub>i</sub> >** пробегает значения от **2** до максимума.
Нетрудно заметить, что:

1. Элементы на главной диагонали соответствуют значениям нулевого элемента автокорреляционной функции, выборки для вычисления которых сдвинуты на один элемент.
2. Элементы на побочной диагонали и первый элемент в столбце свободных членов соответствуют значениям первого элемента автокорреляционной функции, причём элементы на диагонали равны, а выборка для свободного члена сдвинута по отношению к ним.

Это может привести к неожиданным эффектам для последовательностей с сильным возрастающим (убывающим) трендом.

Так, для выборки из первых 10 членов последовательности Фибоначчи
**x<sub>i</sub> = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}**
получается система уравнений вида:
**1869 f<sub>0</sub> + 1155 f<sub>1</sub> = - 3024,**
**1155 f<sub>0</sub> + 714 f<sub>1</sub> = - 1869**
с правильным решением **f<sub>0</sub> = -1, f<sub>1</sub> = -1,** 
но ожидаемой тёплицевой симметрии задачи нет.
При этом использование АКФ даёт систему
**4893 f<sub>0</sub> + 3024 f<sub>1</sub> = - 3024,**
**3024 f<sub>0</sub> + 4893 f<sub>1</sub> = - 1869,**
использование которой в данном случае неправомерно.
Основной метод борьбы с этими эффектами - центрирование выборки.
Но главное - это проверка возможности серьёзного упрощения модели и применения алгоритма Дарбина.

### Алгоритм Дарбина

Суть идеи Дарбина - поиск решения для матрицы размерности **n+1** в виде:
**(f'<sub>0</sub>, f'<sub>1</sub>, ... , f'<sub>n-1</sub>, f'<sub>n</sub>) = (f<sub>0</sub>, f<sub>1</sub>, ... , f<sub>n-1</sub>, 0) + beta (f<sub>n-1</sub>, f<sub>n-2</sub>, ... , f<sub>0</sub>, 1).**
Действительно, подстановка этого решения в матрицу размерности **n+1** с учётом системы размерности **n** даёт:

**-a<sub>1</sub> - beta a<sub>n</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>beta = -a<sub>1</sub>,**
**-a<sub>2</sub> - beta a<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>beta = -a<sub>2</sub>,**
**...**
**-a<sub>n-1</sub> - beta a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>beta = -a<sub>n</sub>,**
**a<sub>n</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>n-2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>n-1</sub> + beta(a<sub>n</sub>f<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>f<sub>n-2</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub>f<sub>n-3</sub> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>) = -a<sub>n+1</sub>.**
Первые **n** уравнений системы удовлетворяются при любом значении **beta,** последнее - при
**beta = - (a<sub>n+1</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>n-2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>n-1</sub>)

/ (a<sub>n</sub>f<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>f<sub>n-2</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub>f<sub>n-3</sub> + ... + a<sub>2</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>f<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>).**

Функция `durbin()` возвращает массив векторов авторегрессии для всего диапазона **n.**
При **n=1 f = (-a<sub>1</sub>/a<sub>0</sub>),** последующие векторы коэффициентов вычисляются рекуррентно (сначала **beta**, затем **f**).

### Программная реализация

В программе на языке PHP реализованы следующие функции:

1. Центрирование массива `center()`.
2. Скалярное произведение векторов со сдвигом второго вектора `scalar_prod()`.
3. Вывод массива с текстовым комментарием `print_array()`.
4. Вывод системы линейных уравнений второго порядка и её решения `print_s()`.
5. Вычисление автокорреляционной функции (АКФ) `acf()`.
6. Сравнение точной и тёплицевой систем второго порядка и их решений для заданной выборки `compare_s()`.
7. Алгоритм Дарбина для решения системы уравнений специального вида `durbin()`.
8. Тестирование алгоритма Дарбина `test_durbin()`.

Текст программы

```
function center(&$arr){
    $len = count($arr);
    $aver = array_sum($arr) / $len; 
    foreach($arr as &$item){
        $item -= $aver;
    }
}

function scalar_prod($a, $b, $shift = 0, &$c = null){
    $scal = 0;
    if(is_null($c)) $cc = []; else $cc = &$c;
    foreach($a as $key => $item){
        $cc[] = $item * $b[$key+$shift];
        $scal += end($cc);
    }
    return  $scal;  
}

function print_array($arr, $str, $n = 11){
    print $str."[";
    foreach($arr as $key => $item){
        if(!(($key+1) % $n)) print "<br>"; 
        printf ("\"%03d\" => %.3f,&ensp;", $key, $item);
    }
    print "]";  
}   

function print_s($a, $b, $str){
    print("<br><br>$str");
    printf("<br> %.3f f0 + %.3f f1 = %.3f", $a[0][0], $a[0][1], $b[0]);
    printf("<br> %.3f f0 + %.3f f1 = %.3f", $a[1][0], $a[1][1], $b[1]);
    $det = $a[0][0]*$a[1][1] - $a[1][0]*$a[0][1];
    $det0 = $b[0]*$a[1][1] - $b[1]*$a[0][1];
    $det1 = $a[0][0]*$b[1] - $a[1][0]*$b[0];
    printf("<br>Решение: f = [%f, %f]", (float)$det0 / $det, (float)$det1/$det);
}

function acf($flow, $k, $center = -1, $len = null){
    if(is_null($len)){
        $len = count($flow);
    }
    $slice = array_slice($flow, $k, $len-$k);
    for($lag = 0; $lag <= $k; $lag++){
        $result[$lag] = scalar_prod($slice, $flow, $k-$lag);
    }
    if($center != -1){
        $denom = 1.0/$result[0];
        foreach($result as &$res){
            $res *= $denom;
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}

function compare_s($test){
    $m = count($test);  
    $acf2 = acf($test, 0, -1, $m-2);
    $acf1 = acf($test, 1, -1, $m-1);
    $acf = acf($test, 2);
    $a_exact = [ [$acf1[0],$acf1[1]], [$acf1[1],$acf2[0]] ];
    $a = [ [$acf[0],$acf[1]], [$acf[1],$acf[0]] ];
    $b = [-$acf[1], -$acf[2]];
    print_s($a_exact, $b, "Контроль симметрии матрицы<br><br>Точная система (порядок 2):");
    print_s($a, $b, "Тёплицева система (порядок 2):");
}

function durbin($acf, $n){
    $ff = [];
    $f = [-$acf[1]/$acf[0]];
    print_array($f, "<br>f = ");
    $ff[] = $f;
    for($r = 1; $r < $n; $r++){
        $acr = array_reverse(array_slice($acf, 0, $r+1));
        $fr = array_reverse($f);
        $fr[] = 1;
        $f[] = 0;
        $beta = - ($acf[$r+1] + scalar_prod($f, $acr))/scalar_prod($fr, $acr);
        print("<br>beta[$r] = $beta ");
        $f = array_map(function($a,$b) use($beta){
            return $a+$beta*$b;
        },$f,$fr);
        $ff[] = $f;
        print_array($f, "&emsp; f = ");
    }
    return $ff;
}

function test_durbin($arr, $n, $center=0){
    $len = count($arr);     
    if($center){
        center($arr);
    } 
    $eps_arr = 0;
    foreach($arr as $item){
        $eps_arr += $item*$item;
    }
    printf("<br><br>Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = %d, длина выборки = $len, СКО выборки = %f):", $n, sqrt($eps_arr/($len-1)));
    $a = acf($arr, $n);
    print_array($a, "<br><br>АКФ: ");
    $ff = durbin($a,$n);
    $c = array_reverse(end($ff));
    $eps = 0;
    $brr = [];
    for($j=$n; $j<$len; $j++){
        $brr[$j] = $arr[$j]+scalar_prod($c, $arr, $j-$n);
        $eps += pow($brr[$j],2);
    }
    $k = count($f)-1;
    printf("<br>СКО остатка = %f", sqrt($eps/($len-$n)));
}

$m = 10;
$test = [1.0, 1,0];
for ($i = 2; $i < $m; $i++){
    $test[$i] = $test[$i-1] + $test[$i-2];
}   
print("*** Фибоначчи - 10: ***");
compare_s($test);
test_durbin($test, 2);

print("<br><br>*** Фибоначчи-10 с центрированием: ***");
test_durbin($test, 2, 1);

$m=2000;
$dpi = 2*M_PI;
for($j=0; $j<$m; $j++) $arr[$j] = sin($j);// - $dpi*floor($j/$dpi));
print("<br><br>*** Авторегрессия по Дарбину (синусная выборка): ***");
compare_s($arr);

test_durbin($arr, 1);
test_durbin($arr, 2);
test_durbin($arr, 3);
test_durbin($arr, 4);
test_durbin($arr, 5);
test_durbin($arr, 6);
```

### Результаты:

```
*** Фибоначчи - 10: ***

Контроль симметрии матрицы

Точная система (порядок 2):
1869.000 f0 + 1155.000 f1 = -3024.000
1155.000 f0 + 714.000 f1 = -1869.000
Решение: f = [-1.000000, -1.000000]

Тёплицева система (порядок 2):
4893.000 f0 + 3024.000 f1 = -3024.000
3024.000 f0 + 4893.000 f1 = -1869.000
Решение: f = [-0.618007, -0.000030]

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 2, длина выборки = 10, СКО выборки = 23.321426):

АКФ: ["000" => 4893.000, "001" => 3024.000, "002" => 1869.000, ]
f = ["000" => -0.618, ]
beta[1] = -2.98035943134E-5   f = ["000" => -0.618, "001" => -0.000, ]
СКО остатка = 15.285024

*** Фибоначчи-10 с центрированием: ***

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 2, длина выборки = 10, СКО выборки = 17.795443):

АКФ: ["000" => 2496.320, "001" => 1399.520, "002" => 716.420, ]
f = ["000" => -0.561, ]
beta[1] = 0.0398418808262   f = ["000" => -0.583, "001" => 0.040, ]
СКО остатка = 12.412102

*** Авторегрессия по Дарбину (синусная выборка): ***

Контроль симметрии матрицы

Точная система (порядок 2):
999.018 f0 + 539.793 f1 = -539.750
539.793 f0 + 999.016 f1 = 415.712
Решение: f = [-1.080605, 1.000000]

Тёплицева система (порядок 2):
998.969 f0 + 539.750 f1 = -539.750
539.750 f0 + 998.969 f1 = 415.712
Решение: f = [-1.080619, 1.000008]

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 1, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 999.677, "001" => 539.750, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
СКО остатка = 0.595153

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 2, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 998.969, "001" => 539.750, "002" => -415.712, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
beta[1] = 1.00000781118   f = ["000" => -1.081, "001" => 1.000, ]
СКО остатка = 0.000009

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 3, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 998.142, "001" => 538.985, "002" => -415.712, "003" => -988.206, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
beta[1] = 0.999521483275   f = ["000" => -1.080, "001" => 1.000, ]
beta[2] = 0.925724185475   f = ["000" => -0.154, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.926, ]
СКО остатка = 0.000488

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 4, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 998.122, "001" => 538.857, "002" => -415.831, "003" => -988.206, "004" => -652.029, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
beta[1] = 0.999342177677   f = ["000" => -1.079, "001" => 0.999, ]
beta[2] = 0.925843078378   f = ["000" => -0.154, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.926, ]
beta[3] = 6.00603640925   f = ["000" => 5.406, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.000, "003" => 6.006, ]
СКО остатка = 0.004358

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 5, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 997.550, "001" => 538.964, "002" => -415.143, "003" => -987.569, "004" => -652.029, "005" => 282.984, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
beta[1] = 0.999977661062   f = ["000" => -1.081, "001" => 1.000, ]
beta[2] = 0.925422594935   f = ["000" => -0.155, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.925, ]
beta[3] = 5.96426000454   f = ["000" => 5.364, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.000, "003" => 5.964, ]
beta[4] = -1.11184318911   f = ["000" => -1.267, "001" => -0.000, "002" => 0.000, "003" => 0.000, "004" => -1.112, ]
СКО остатка = 0.000027

Решение по Дарбину (порядок АР = 6, длина выборки = 2000, СКО выборки = 0.707169):

АКФ: ["000" => 996.630, "001" => 538.238, "002" => -415.008, "003" => -986.697, "004" => -651.222, "005" => 282.984, "006" => 957.015, ]
f = ["000" => -0.540, ]
beta[1] = 0.999627453765   f = ["000" => -1.080, "001" => 1.000, ]
beta[2] = 0.925654012051   f = ["000" => -0.155, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.926, ]
beta[3] = 5.98719502289   f = ["000" => 5.387, "001" => 0.000, "002" => 0.000, "003" => 5.987, ]
beta[4] = -1.11131942365   f = ["000" => -1.266, "001" => -0.000, "002" => -0.000, "003" => 0.000, "004" => -1.111, ]
beta[5] = -0.877666481891   f = ["000" => -0.291, "001" => -0.000, "002" => -0.000, "003" => 0.000, "004" => -0.000, "005" => -0.878, ]
СКО остатка = 0.000360
```

Программа показала высокую эффективность на ограниченной (синусной) выборке при большом объёме исходных данных.

Comment: Есть англоязычный перевод: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887709/given-a-sequence-a-k-in-mathbbr-find-the-periodicity-of-sum-limits-k-s/1906343#1906343

Answer (score 5):

Ваш массив элементов можно представить как значение некоторой функции в точках 1, 2, 3... N

Тогда, для поиска нового значения (с аргументом функции N+1), можно использовать [интерполирование по Ньютону](http://school-collection.edu.ru/catalog/res/f38c88e8-8328-443f-b1e8-d215a9dd734d/view/). Программирует это довольно просто.

Так мы найдём многочлен P(x), который принимает значение a[i] из массива в ячейке с индексом i (т.е. P(i) = a[i]), тогда, чтобы найти a[N+1] значение, просто подставим в этот многочлен вместо x, значение N+1. Т.е. ответ = P(N+1).

Comment: Отличный вариант, спасибо, пробую реализовать.

Comment: Только врятли что-то хорошее получится. Многочлен будет слишком большой степени.

Comment: Про максимальное значение N ничего не говорили. Ну даже, если N=10^6, то можно использовать бинарное возведение в степень.

Comment: N = 300-400

Comment: Ну, тогда всё хорошо

Comment: Я не про вычислительную сложность говорю, а про проблему переобучения. Можете почитать статью http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting, там картинка очень примечательная.

Comment: Можно попробовать этот многочлен ограничить, например, тридцатью значениями последних путей.

Answer (score 3):

На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа, все зависит от того, какую зависимость представляет ваш ряд. Рекомендую попробовать [метод наименьших квадратов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) - это несложный метод, особенно если предположить, что зависимость линейная.

Comment: Да, вы правы об этом я и забыл. Значения случайны, поэтому я написал в вопросе "предсказание".

Answer (score 3):

Кроме нейронной сети есть еще такой интересный алгоритм: [муравьиный](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Муравьиный_алгоритм) :)

Применив к вашей системе, он будет работать как-то так: предположим, что источнику сигнала при попытке соединения могут дать следующие ответы: подтвеждение готовности передачи или отказ.
При передаче - увеличиваем "привлекательность" ПП на какую-то величину "А",
при отказе - уменьшаем на "Б".
"А", "Б"- надо найти экспериментальным путем для оптимальной работы системы. Кроме того надо будет настроить максимумы для счетчиков "привлекательности" и уменьшения счетчика со временем.