# Генератор чисел логнормального распределения

Tags: алгоритм, java

Здравствуйте!

Был у меня здесь недавно [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95184/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), пошел я по пути формирования нового значения, базирующемся на распределении вероятности. Спасибо большое @neofit !

Получилась интересная картина, очень напоминающая лонормальное распределение:

[распределение http://upload.dexstudio.com.ua/botva2.jpg](http://upload.dexstudio.com.ua/botva2.jpg)

Теперь, собственно, вопрос, как генерировать число из этого распределения? Есть готовые решения, например, для Java, которые способны принимать данное распределение и выдавать значение где-то среди этой красоты?

Comment: Есть такая [статья](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Comment: @Андрей, мне по распределению нужно получить не новое распределение, а лишь новое число из исходного.

Comment: @Dex, рекомендую обратить внимание на [квантильное преобразование](http://www.nsu.ru/mmf/tvims/chernova/tv/lec/node32.html): получение случайной величины заданного распределения из равномерного.

Comment: @AlexeyM, да, видел уже, но не придумал, как реализовать.

Comment: @Dex, например, на [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.83.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B8.D0.BD) указан способ: моделируем нормально распределённую случайную величину X, затем Y = Exp[X] и есть искомая величина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:
Вам нужно чтобы событие 1 произошло с шансом 75%, событие 2 с шансом 10%, событие 3 с шансом 15%. Генерируете случайное число от 0 до 99. Если число в интервале 0-74, то событие 1, 75-84 событие 2, 85-99 событие 3.
В Вашем вопросе все тоже самое. Сумма длин всех полосок- это число 99 в примере. Длина каждой полоски задает интервал попадания.

Comment: Реализовал, спасибо, еще один шаг сделан. Правда неустойчивость такого варианта меня не совсем устраивает. Хочется нечто более устойчивое, которое не просто "выскакивает" случайным образом, а зависит несколько от предыдущих значений. Но вот как...

Answer (score 2):

Делаем так:

1. Если мы считаем, что наш набор экспериментальных значений похож на логнормальное распределение, то берем функцию аппроксимирующую логнормальное распределение - например [эту](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CB%EE%E3%ED%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5_%F0%E0%F1%EF%F0%E5%E4%E5%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5) (по сути гаусс с логарифмами)
2. Далее методом [наименьших квадратов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%E5%F2%EE%E4_%ED%E0%E8%EC%E5%ED%FC%F8%E8%F5_%EA%E2%E0%E4%F0%E0%F2%EE%E2), находим 2 параметра логнормального распределения (в классике сигма задает "толщину", а мю - задает положение экстремума)
3. Далее спокойно подставляем в полученную функцию значения и генератор готов.