# Предсказать дату

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, ruby, дата

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть массив класса Time:

```
arr = [..., 2014-08-21 18:00:15 UTC, 2014-08-21 17:58:32 UTC, 2014-08-21 17:32:35 UTC, 2014-08-21 17:20:16 UTC, ...]
```

На основе этого хочу предсказать следующую дату. Как это лучше сделать?

**Уточнения вопроса**:
В массиве история с датами, на этом основании нужно сделать предположения следующей даты.

**Уточнения вопроса 2**:
4 даты в массиве - это просто пример, меньше 10-20 не будет, также они будут все время обновляться, что дает возможность проверить правильность прогноза.

**Уточнения вопроса 3**:
Нашел [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95184/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), только там случайные числа.

Comment: @sooik, это не форум телепатов и гадалок, поясните, что значит "предсказать".

Comment: надо просто найти апи к http://vanga.ru/

*извините*

Comment: Даты это просто числа (скажем, приводятся к числу секунд начиная с ...).

Поэтому ищите в области аппроксимации функций. Обычно все эти предсказания относят к статистике. 

Посмотрите для начала, например, [метод наименьших квадратов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), а вообще погуглите на тему *экстраполяция*.

Answer (score 1):

[Эрмитова интерполяция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эрмитова_интерполяция). 
[Метод наименьших квадратов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).
[Сплайны](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD). Все это для приближения значения функции.

Comment: Спасибо! Читаю.