# Дедлочная генерация случайных чисел

Tags: алгоритм, .net, многопоточность, случайные-числа

Это исправленная версия вопроса [Насколько случайны данные, сгенерированные таким образом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484669/178988)

Есть два потока, захватывающие блокировку в разном порядке, что приводит к дедлокам. Для генерации каждого следующего бита производится ожидание дедлока и проверка чётности числа инкрементов в первом потоке. Для увеличения длины цепочки на каждой итерации делается sleep(0). Также делается проверка, что первый поток успел выполнить хотя бы 4 инкремента.

Вопрос тот же: насколько случайны генерируемые таким образом значения?

Изменения по сравнению с предыдущем кодом:

- Исправлена некорректная работа с блокировками
- Добавлена проверка на 4 или более инкремента в первом потоке
- `SemaphoreSlim` заменён на `Semaphore`
- Все ожидания сделаны через стандартные блокировки

Исправленный код:

```vb
Imports System.Threading

Public Module ThreadRandom
  Dim Value1 As Integer, Value2 As Integer
  Dim Sem1 As New Semaphore(1, 1), Sem2 As New Semaphore(1, 1)

  Dim ReleaseToStartThreads As New Semaphore(1, 1), ReleaseToProvideBit As New Semaphore(1, 1)
  Dim ThreadsInsideFirstLock As Integer

  Private Sub Inc(SemA As Semaphore, SemB As Semaphore, ByRef Value As Integer)
    Do
      ReleaseToStartThreads.WaitOne()
      ReleaseToStartThreads.Release()
      Do
        Thread.Sleep(0)

        SemA.WaitOne()
        If Interlocked.Increment(ThreadsInsideFirstLock) = 2 Then
          ReleaseToStartThreads.WaitOne()
          SemA.Release()
          Exit Do
        End If

        SemB.WaitOne()
        If Interlocked.Decrement(ThreadsInsideFirstLock) = 1 Then
          Volatile.Write(ThreadsInsideFirstLock, 0)
          SemB.Release()
          SemA.Release()
          ReleaseToProvideBit.Release()
          Exit Do
        End If

        Interlocked.Increment(Value)
        SemB.Release()
        SemA.Release()
      Loop
    Loop
  End Sub

  Private Sub Init()
    ReleaseToStartThreads.WaitOne()
    Call (New Thread(Sub() Inc(Sem1, Sem2, Value1))).Start()
    Call (New Thread(Sub() Inc(Sem2, Sem1, Value2))).Start()
  End Sub

  Public Function GetRandBit() As Integer
    Do
      Volatile.Write(Value1, 0)
      ReleaseToProvideBit.WaitOne()
      ReleaseToStartThreads.Release()
      ReleaseToProvideBit.WaitOne()
      ReleaseToProvideBit.Release()
      Dim Res = Volatile.Read(Value1)
      If Res > 3 Then Return Res And 1
    Loop
  End Function

  Sub Main()
    Init()
    Do
      Console.WriteLine(GetRandBit())
    Loop Until Console.KeyAvailable
  End Sub
End Module
```

Пример сгенерированных данных:

> 0110001111111111111110101100110010110111100000111110101001011010101001011110001111001110000000101111111111001011001011011111111000100010100111101010101010000110010011000001011100101101101000101001100001100101010010101010010111011001010010100110000111100100110110100000110000001101101100111010101000111111000000001101100001101111100010010010111001011011001010111000000101111010010011011110111011010010100011100010100001011111011001000100011001100110100101111001111110101001010010110000110000000000101000110111100101011110001011001110010011111110010011011110011110011100100111101111000001000001011011111000101000001010000101111110011101001000100001001010010101110100011011100100111101100100111001100001011100011011010111001111000010000111011011000010001010010111011100011111100110010101100111110010000100110011111001010011111000110001001100001100011100110110100011010000001001011001111110100001100010000110000110110011000011100110100011010111010110110001000011101000100111010101101000011000111011111000100101101010100011000000

Статистика последовательностей различной длины по ним:

```
1
0 512
1 512

2
00 123
01 120
10 146
11 123

3
000 40
001 44
010 42
011 44
100 45
101 47
110 38
111 41

4
0000 16
0001 14
0010 15
0011 13
0100 16
0101 14
0110 18
0111 15
1000 20
1001 17
1010 22
1011 9
1100 13
1101 12
1110 23
1111 19

5
00000 5
00001 5
00010 2
00011 6
00100 2
00101 7
00110 8
00111 5
01000 9
01001 4
01010 9
01011 8
01100 10
01101 4
01110 4
01111 12
10000 8
10001 4
10010 13
10011 7
10100 6
10101 5
10110 5
10111 5
11000 8
11001 10
11010 7
11011 5
11100 7
11101 2
11110 6
11111 6
```

Статистика посчитана следующим образом:

```vb
Public Iterator Function GetRandBits() As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
  Do
    Yield GetRandBit()
  Loop
End Function

Public Function RunTest(N As Integer) As Integer(,)
  Dim Vals(8) As Integer, Count(Vals.Length - 1, (1 << Vals.Length) - 1) As Integer, I As Integer = 0

  For Each X In GetRandBits().Take(N)
    Console.Write(X)
    I += 1
    For Q = 1 To Vals.Length - 1
      Vals(Q) = ((Vals(Q) << 1) Or X) And ((1 << Q) - 1)
      If I Mod Q = 0 Then
        Count(Q, Vals(Q)) += 1
      End If
    Next Q
  Next X

  Console.WriteLine()
  Return Count
End Function

Sub Main()
  Init()

  Dim Count = RunTest(1024)

  For Q = 0 To Count.GetLength(0) - 1
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine(Q)
    For W = 0 To (1 << Q) - 1
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Convert.ToString(W, 2).PadLeft(Q, "0"c), Count(Q, W))
    Next W
  Next Q

  Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

## Результат запуска теста [Diehard](http://stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/)

Точнее, `diequick.exe`, т. к. полный не помещается в ответ.

```
 BIRTHDAY SPACINGS TEST, M= 512 N=2**24 LAMBDA=  2.0000
           my.bin          using bits  1 to 24 p-value=  .767240
           my.bin          using bits  2 to 25 p-value=  .354530
           my.bin          using bits  3 to 26 p-value=  .897101
           my.bin          using bits  4 to 27 p-value=  .421615
           my.bin          using bits  5 to 28 p-value=  .423124
           my.bin          using bits  6 to 29 p-value=  .801772
           my.bin          using bits  7 to 30 p-value=  .057523
           my.bin          using bits  8 to 31 p-value=  .373922
           my.bin          using bits  9 to 32 p-value=  .828247
   The 9 p-values were
        .767240   .354530   .897101   .421615   .423124
        .801772   .057523   .373922   .828247
  A KSTEST for the 9 p-values yields  .266910
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           OPERM5 test for file my.bin         
 chisquare for 99 degrees of freedom= 86.430; p-value= .187632
           OPERM5 test for file my.bin         
 chisquare for 99 degrees of freedom= 93.215; p-value= .354952
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Binary rank test for my.bin         
         Rank test for 31x31 binary matrices:
        rows from leftmost 31 bits of each 32-bit integer
      rank   observed  expected (o-e)^2/e  sum
        28       223     211.4   .634489     .634
        29      5173    5134.0   .296104     .931
        30     23069   23103.0   .050175     .981
        31     11535   11551.5   .023638    1.004
  chisquare= 1.004 for 3 d. of f.; p-value= .357938
    Binary rank test for my.bin         
         Rank test for 32x32 binary matrices:
        rows from leftmost 32 bits of each 32-bit integer
      rank   observed  expected (o-e)^2/e  sum
        29       207     211.4   .092324     .092
        30      5134    5134.0   .000000     .092
        31     23185   23103.0   .290711     .383
        32     11474   11551.5   .520281     .903
  chisquare=  .903 for 3 d. of f.; p-value= .346320
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 b-rank test for bits  1 to  8 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  2 to  9 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  3 to 10 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  4 to 11 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  5 to 12 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  6 to 13 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  7 to 14 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  8 to 15 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits  9 to 16 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 10 to 17 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 11 to 18 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 12 to 19 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 13 to 20 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 14 to 21 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 15 to 22 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 16 to 23 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 17 to 24 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 18 to 25 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 19 to 26 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 20 to 27 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 21 to 28 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 22 to 29 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 23 to 30 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 24 to 31 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
 b-rank test for bits 25 to 32 p=1-exp(-SUM/2)=1.00000
   TEST SUMMARY, 25 tests on 100,000 random 6x8 matrices
 These should be 25 uniform [0,1] random variables:
    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
   brank test summary for my.bin         
       The KS test for those 25 supposed UNI's yields
                    KS p-value=1.000000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  No. missing words should average  141909. with sigma=428.
 tst no  1:  156458 missing words,   33.99 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  2:  152017 missing words,   23.62 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  3:  149435 missing words,   17.58 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  4:  154834 missing words,   30.20 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  5:  157563 missing words,   36.57 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  6:  155332 missing words,   31.36 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  7:  158934 missing words,   39.78 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  8:  158521 missing words,   38.81 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no  9:  151892 missing words,   23.32 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 10:  153349 missing words,   26.73 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 11:  153664 missing words,   27.46 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 12:  163298 missing words,   49.97 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 13:  160763 missing words,   44.05 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 14:  157426 missing words,   36.25 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 15:  156789 missing words,   34.77 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 16:  156807 missing words,   34.81 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 17:  157387 missing words,   36.16 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 18:  157349 missing words,   36.07 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 19:  157250 missing words,   35.84 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
 tst no 20:  152518 missing words,   24.79 sigmas from mean, p-value=1.00000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 23 to 32        156293 49.599 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 22 to 31        155822 47.975 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 21 to 30        155646 47.368 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 20 to 29        156246 49.437 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 19 to 28        156079 48.861 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 18 to 27        155927 48.337 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 17 to 26        155284 46.120 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 16 to 25        155413 46.564 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 15 to 24        156556 50.506 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 14 to 23        155634 47.326 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 13 to 22        155866 48.126 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 12 to 21        155694 47.533 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 11 to 20        155531 46.971 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits 10 to 19        155730 47.657 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  9 to 18        155615 47.261 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  8 to 17        155887 48.199 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  7 to 16        155550 47.037 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  6 to 15        155643 47.357 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  5 to 14        155326 46.264 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  4 to 13        156122 49.009 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  3 to 12        156037 48.716 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  2 to 11        156385 49.916 1.0000
    OPSO for my.bin          using bits  1 to 10        156089 48.895 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 28 to 32        155768 46.979 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 27 to 31        155483 46.012 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 26 to 30        155967 47.653 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 25 to 29        156241 48.582 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 24 to 28        155874 47.338 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 23 to 27        156491 49.429 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 22 to 26        156262 48.653 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 21 to 25        155826 47.175 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 20 to 24        156147 48.263 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 19 to 23        154981 44.311 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 18 to 22        155793 47.063 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 17 to 21        156111 48.141 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 16 to 20        155881 47.362 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 15 to 19        156394 49.101 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 14 to 18        156007 47.789 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 13 to 17        155993 47.741 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 12 to 16        156206 48.463 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 11 to 15        156024 47.846 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits 10 to 14        155775 47.002 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  9 to 13        155849 47.253 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  8 to 12        155985 47.714 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  7 to 11        156268 48.673 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  6 to 10        155891 47.395 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  5 to  9        155247 45.212 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  4 to  8        155822 47.162 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  3 to  7        155548 46.233 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  2 to  6        156194 48.423 1.0000
    OQSO for my.bin          using bits  1 to  5        155786 47.040 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 31 to 32        155338 39.613 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 30 to 31        155410 39.825 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 29 to 30        155743 40.807 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 28 to 29        155861 41.155 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 27 to 28        156324 42.521 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 26 to 27        155826 41.052 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 25 to 26        155834 41.076 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 24 to 25        156463 42.931 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 23 to 24        156441 42.866 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 22 to 23        155249 39.350 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 21 to 22        155987 41.527 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 20 to 21        156618 43.388 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 19 to 20        155935 41.374 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 18 to 19        155870 41.182 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 17 to 18        155297 39.492 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 16 to 17        155312 39.536 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 15 to 16        156403 42.754 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 14 to 15        156215 42.200 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 13 to 14        156572 43.253 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 12 to 13        155869 41.179 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 11 to 12        155918 41.324 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits 10 to 11        156355 42.613 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  9 to 10        155844 41.105 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  8 to  9        156192 42.132 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  7 to  8        156155 42.023 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  6 to  7        155600 40.385 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  5 to  6        155380 39.736 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  4 to  5        156293 42.430 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  3 to  4        156002 41.571 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  2 to  3        156051 41.716 1.0000
     DNA for my.bin          using bits  1 to  2        156146 41.996 1.0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Test results for my.bin         
 Chi-square with 5^5-5^4=2500 d.of f. for sample size:2560000
                               chisquare  equiv normal  p-value
  Results fo COUNT-THE-1's in successive bytes:
 byte stream for my.bin          53679.34    723.785     1.000000
 byte stream for my.bin          63617.41    864.331     1.000000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Chi-square with 5^5-5^4=2500 d.of f. for sample size: 256000
                      chisquare  equiv normal  p value
  Results for COUNT-THE-1's in specified bytes:
           bits  1 to  8  7407.36     69.401     1.000000
           bits  2 to  9  7559.53     71.553     1.000000
           bits  3 to 10  7307.10     67.983     1.000000
           bits  4 to 11  7104.61     65.119     1.000000
           bits  5 to 12  7196.77     66.422     1.000000
           bits  6 to 13  7251.05     67.190     1.000000
           bits  7 to 14  7112.07     65.225     1.000000
           bits  8 to 15  7231.46     66.913     1.000000
           bits  9 to 16  7350.88     68.602     1.000000
           bits 10 to 17  7131.99     65.506     1.000000
           bits 11 to 18  7108.68     65.177     1.000000
           bits 12 to 19  7161.25     65.920     1.000000
           bits 13 to 20  7097.92     65.024     1.000000
           bits 14 to 21  7278.48     67.578     1.000000
           bits 15 to 22  7206.23     66.556     1.000000
           bits 16 to 23  7263.24     67.362     1.000000
           bits 17 to 24  7145.13     65.692     1.000000
           bits 18 to 25  6973.44     63.264     1.000000
           bits 19 to 26  7013.83     63.835     1.000000
           bits 20 to 27  6861.11     61.675     1.000000
           bits 21 to 28  7083.25     64.817     1.000000
           bits 22 to 29  6951.65     62.956     1.000000
           bits 23 to 30  7003.80     63.693     1.000000
           bits 24 to 31  7048.20     64.321     1.000000
           bits 25 to 32  7168.59     66.024     1.000000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           CDPARK: result of ten tests on file my.bin         
            Of 12,000 tries, the average no. of successes
                 should be 3523 with sigma=21.9
            Successes: 3455    z-score: -3.105 p-value: .000951
            Successes: 3535    z-score:   .548 p-value: .708135
            Successes: 3549    z-score:  1.187 p-value: .882429
            Successes: 3487    z-score: -1.644 p-value: .050105
            Successes: 3501    z-score: -1.005 p-value: .157553
            Successes: 3518    z-score:  -.228 p-value: .409702
            Successes: 3482    z-score: -1.872 p-value: .030593
            Successes: 3541    z-score:   .822 p-value: .794438
            Successes: 3503    z-score:  -.913 p-value: .180558
            Successes: 3516    z-score:  -.320 p-value: .374623

           square size   avg. no.  parked   sample sigma
             100.            3508.700       27.675
            KSTEST for the above 10: p=  .921880
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               This is the MINIMUM DISTANCE test
              for random integers in the file my.bin         
     Sample no.    d^2     avg     equiv uni            
           5     .5862   1.2281     .445207
          10     .7432   1.0443     .526188
          15     .2731   1.0501     .240048
          20     .0259   1.0207     .025719
          25    2.6775   1.0521     .932185
          30     .7625   1.3070     .535268
          35     .5515   1.1838     .425498
          40     .7224   1.1154     .516158
          45    1.8330   1.1069     .841538
          50    1.8413   1.0533     .842856
          55     .1526   1.0042     .142143
          60     .2330    .9749     .208795
          65    2.2443   1.0046     .895190
          70     .1343    .9615     .126230
          75     .5971    .9201     .451248
          80     .4956    .9096     .392283
          85    1.6687    .9024     .813088
          90    1.5895    .8972     .797597
          95    4.2772    .9225     .986413
         100     .6649    .9170     .487380
     MINIMUM DISTANCE TEST for my.bin         
          Result of KS test on 20 transformed mindist^2's:
                                  p-value= .410748
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               The 3DSPHERES test for file my.bin         
 sample no:  1     r^3=   4.045     p-value= .12614
 sample no:  2     r^3=   5.208     p-value= .15935
 sample no:  3     r^3=  20.867     p-value= .50121
 sample no:  4     r^3=   2.879     p-value= .09151
 sample no:  5     r^3=   4.857     p-value= .14947
 sample no:  6     r^3=  67.355     p-value= .89409
 sample no:  7     r^3=  46.151     p-value= .78527
 sample no:  8     r^3=  37.896     p-value= .71725
 sample no:  9     r^3=   6.410     p-value= .19239
 sample no: 10     r^3=  27.144     p-value= .59538
 sample no: 11     r^3=  19.925     p-value= .48531
 sample no: 12     r^3=  24.073     p-value= .55177
 sample no: 13     r^3=   7.818     p-value= .22942
 sample no: 14     r^3=  60.070     p-value= .86498
 sample no: 15     r^3=  66.429     p-value= .89077
 sample no: 16     r^3=  10.644     p-value= .29868
 sample no: 17     r^3=  38.478     p-value= .72268
 sample no: 18     r^3=  13.504     p-value= .36246
 sample no: 19     r^3=  24.871     p-value= .56353
 sample no: 20     r^3=   8.005     p-value= .23420
       3DSPHERES test for file my.bin               p-value= .189022
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            RESULTS OF SQUEEZE TEST FOR my.bin         
         Table of standardized frequency counts
     ( (obs-exp)/sqrt(exp) )^2
        for j taking values <=6,7,8,...,47,>=48:
     -.1     2.2     1.1     5.7     4.5     8.2
     8.9     7.9     9.0    10.3     9.0     5.6
     4.5     2.6      .8    -1.0    -3.7    -2.3
    -4.2    -4.5    -7.3    -3.6    -2.2    -3.0
    -3.1    -1.7     -.2     -.3    -1.6     -.2
    -2.3      .4     -.3     -.1      .3     1.0
      .5     1.1      .1     1.0      .9    -1.0
     1.8
           Chi-square with 42 degrees of freedom:762.336
              z-score= 78.595  p-value=1.000000
______________________________________________________________
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Test no.  1      p-value  .528071
                Test no.  2      p-value  .814209
                Test no.  3      p-value  .184899
                Test no.  4      p-value  .669492
                Test no.  5      p-value  .997071
                Test no.  6      p-value  .983988
                Test no.  7      p-value  .906373
                Test no.  8      p-value  .104943
                Test no.  9      p-value  .543622
                Test no. 10      p-value  .717526
   Results of the OSUM test for my.bin         
        KSTEST on the above 10 p-values:  .895621
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           The RUNS test for file my.bin         
     Up and down runs in a sample of 10000
_________________________________________________ 
                 Run test for my.bin         :
       runs up; ks test for 10 p's: .715513
     runs down; ks test for 10 p's: .561298
                 Run test for my.bin         :
       runs up; ks test for 10 p's: .442731
     runs down; ks test for 10 p's: .889942
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Results of craps test for my.bin         
  No. of wins:  Observed Expected
                                98513    98585.86
 Chisq=  31.10 for 20 degrees of freedom, p=  .94617
               Throws Observed Expected  Chisq     Sum
            SUMMARY  FOR my.bin         
                p-value for no. of wins: .372261
                p-value for throws/game: .946165
  Test completed.  File my.bin         
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**
Протестировал выборку на сходство с детерминированной и случайной последовательностями, имеющими примерно равное количество нулей и единиц.

Сравнение велось по следующим тестам.

1. Тест на подпоследовательности и их корреляцию с последующим элементом (до 7 элементов).
   Количество и степень детерминированности подпоследовательностей совпали со случайной выборкой, в то время как синусная выборка дала большое количество полностью детерминированных подпоследовательностей.
2. Тест на максимумы автокорреляционной функции (АКФ).
   Тест АКФ совпал со случайной выборкой (отсутствие существенных корреляций), в то время как в синусной выборке присутствуют практически полные корреляции.
3. Тест на авторегрессию данных по Левинсону - Дарбину, [подробные объяснения здесь.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95184/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/468364#468364)
   При увеличении порядка авторегрессии СКО падает незначительно и монотонно, как и для случайной выборки. В то же время резкое снижение СКО синусной выборки указывает на авторегрессивные зависимости.

Вывод: Выборка реальных данных проявила полное сходство со случайной последовательностью и явное отличие от детерминированной (синусной).

Программа:

```
set_time_limit(300);
$str_real = "0110001111111111111110101100110010110111100000111110101001011010101001011110001111001110000000101111111111001011001011011111111000100010100111101010101010000110010011000001011100101101101000101001100001100101010010101010010111011001010010100110000111100100110110100000110000001101101100111010101000111111000000001101100001101111100010010010111001011011001010111000000101111010010011011110111011010010100011100010100001011111011001000100011001100110100101111001111110101001010010110000110000000000101000110111100101011110001011001110010011111110010011011110011110011100100111101111000001000001011011111000101000001010000101111110011101001000100001001010010101110100011011100100111101100100111001100001011100011011010111001111000010000111011011000010001010010111011100011111100110010101100111110010000100110011111001010011111000110001001100001100011100110110100011010000001001011001111110100001100010000110000110110011000011100110100011010111010110110001000011101000100111010101101000011000111011111000100101101010100011000000";

function samples($flow, $k){
    $trans = [];
    for($i=0; $i<65536; $i++){ 
        $str = sprintf("%016b", $i);
        $trans[$str] = $i;
    }
    $len = strlen($flow);
    $cnt_num = (1 << $k);
    for ($num = 0; $num < $cnt_num; $num++){ // для каждого сэмпла
        $st = substr(sprintf("%016b",$num), -$k, $k);
        $sum = 0;
        $sum1 =0;
        for($i = $k-1; $i < $len; $i++){
            $n = substr($flow,$i-$k,$k);
            $n = str_pad($n, 16, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $n = $trans[$n];
            if($n == $num){
                $sum++;
                $sum1 += $flow[$i];
            } 
        }
        if($sum) $result[$st] = sprintf("%5.3f = $sum1/$sum", $sum1/$sum);
    }
    return $result; 
}

function test_samples($arr, $n){
    print "<br>АНАЛИЗ ПОДПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЕЙ<br>";
    for($k=1; $k <= $n; $k++){
        $sam = samples($arr, $k);
        arsort($sam);
        print "<br>$k-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:";
        $order = 0;
        $prn = 0;
        foreach($sam as $key=>$item){
            if($order == $k){
                $prn = 0;
            }
            if(($order < $k) || ($order >= ((1<<$k)-$k))){
                if(($prn++ % 5) == 0) print"<br>";
                $kk = substr(sprintf("%016d",$key),-$k, $k); 
                print "\"$kk\" => $item&emsp;";
            }
            $order++;
        }
    }
}

function center(&$arr){
    $len = count($arr);
    $aver = array_sum($arr) / $len; 
    foreach($arr as &$item){
        $item -= $aver;
    }
}

function scalar_prod($a, $b, $shift = 0, &$c = null){
    $scal = 0;
    if(is_null($c)) $cc = []; else $cc = &$c;
    foreach($a as $key => $item){
        $cc[] = $item * $b[$key+$shift];
        $scal += end($cc);
    }
    return  $scal;  
}

function print_array($arr, $str, $n = 11){
    print $str."[";
    foreach($arr as $key => $item){
        if(!(($key+1) % $n)) print "<br>"; 
        printf ("\"%03d\" => %.3f,&ensp;", $key, $item);
    }
    print "]";  
}   

function print_s($a, $b, $str){
    print("<br><br>$str");
    printf("<br> %.3f f0 + %.3f f1 = %.3f", $a[0][0], $a[0][1], $b[0]);
    printf("<br> %.3f f0 + %.3f f1 = %.3f", $a[1][0], $a[1][1], $b[1]);
    $det = $a[0][0]*$a[1][1] - $a[1][0]*$a[0][1];
    $det0 = $b[0]*$a[1][1] - $b[1]*$a[0][1];
    $det1 = $a[0][0]*$b[1] - $a[1][0]*$b[0];
    printf("<br>Решение: f = [%f, %f]", (float)$det0 / $det, (float)$det1/$det);
}

function acf($ar_flow, $k, $center = -1, $len = null){
    if(is_null($len)){
        $len = count($flow);
    }
    $slice = array_slice($ar_flow, $k, $len-$k);
    for($lag = 0; $lag <= $k; $lag++){
        $result[$lag] = scalar_prod($slice, $ar_flow, $k-$lag);
    }
    if($center != -1){
        $denom = 1.0/$result[0];
        foreach($result as &$res){
            $res *= $denom;
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}

function compare_s($test){
    $m = count($test);  
    $acf2 = acf($test, 0, -1, $m-2);
    $acf1 = acf($test, 1, -1, $m-1);
    $acf = acf($test, 2);
    $a_exact = [ [$acf1[0],$acf1[1]], [$acf1[1],$acf2[0]] ];
    $a = [ [$acf[0],$acf[1]], [$acf[1],$acf[0]] ];
    $b = [-$acf[1], -$acf[2]];
    print_s($a_exact, $b, "Контроль симметрии матрицы<br><br>Точная система (порядок 2):");
    print_s($a, $b, "Тёплицева система (порядок 2):");
}

function durbin($acf, $n){
    $ff = [];
    $f = [-$acf[1]/$acf[0]];
    $ff[] = $f;
    for($r = 1; $r < $n; $r++){
        $acr = array_reverse(array_slice($acf, 0, $r+1));
        $fr = array_reverse($f);
        $fr[] = 1;
        $f[] = 0;
        $beta = - ($acf[$r+1] + scalar_prod($f, $acr))/scalar_prod($fr, $acr);
        $f = array_map(function($a,$b) use($beta){
            return $a+$beta*$b;
        },$f,$fr);
        $ff[] = $f;
    }
    return $ff;
}

function test_durbin($arr, $a, $n, $center=0){
    printf("АВТОРЕГРЕССИЯ ПО ДАРБИНУ");
    compare_s($arr);    
    $len = count($arr);     
    if($center){
        center($arr);
    } 
    $eps_arr = 0;
    foreach($arr as $item){
        $eps_arr += $item*$item;
    }
    printf("<br><br>Порядок АР = %d, длина выборки = $len, СКО выборки = %f):", $n, sqrt($eps_arr/($len-1)));
    $s = [];
    $ff = durbin($a,$n);
    foreach($ff as $key => $f){
        $c = array_reverse($f);
        $eps = 0;
        $brr = [];
        for($j=$n; $j<$len; $j++){
            $brr[$j] = $arr[$j]+scalar_prod($c, $arr, $j-$n);
            $eps += pow($brr[$j],2);
        }
        $k = count($f)-1;
        $s[$key+1] = sqrt($eps/($len-$n));
    }
    return $s;
}

function analytics($str_data){
    print $str_data;
    $len_data = strlen($str_data);
    printf("<br>Длина последовательности = %d <br>", $len_data);
    $array_data = [];
    for($i=0; $i<$len_data; $i++){
        $array_data[$i] = (int)$str_data[$i];
    }
    test_samples($str_data, 7);
    $n = 100;
    $a = acf($array_data, $n, 1);
    $acf1 = $a;
    arsort($acf1);
    print("<br><br>МАКСИМУМЫ АКФ (из $n):");
    var_dump(array_slice($acf1, 0, 10, TRUE));
    $sko = test_durbin($array_data, $a, $n);
    print_array($sko, "<br>CKO: <br>");
}

print("*** РЕАЛЬНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ ***<br><br>");
analytics($str_real);

$m = strlen($str_real);
$str_sin = "";
for($j=0; $j<$m; $j++) $str_sin .= (sin($j) > 0.0) ? "1" : "0";
print("<br><br>*** ОКРУГЛЁННЫЙ СИНУС ***<br><br>");
analytics($str_sin);

$str_mt_rand = "";
for($i=0; $i<$m; $i++){
    $str_mt_rand .= (mt_rand() > (getrandmax()/2)) ? 1 : 0;
}
print("<br><br>*** ДАТЧИК mt_rand() ***<br><br>");
analytics($str_mt_rand);
```

Результаты:

```
*** РЕАЛЬНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ ***

0110001111111111111110101100110010110111100000111110101001011010101001011110001111001110000000101111111111001011001011011111111000100010100111101010101010000110010011000001011100101101101000101001100001100101010010101010010111011001010010100110000111100100110110100000110000001101101100111010101000111111000000001101100001101111100010010010111001011011001010111000000101111010010011011110111011010010100011100010100001011111011001000100011001100110100101111001111110101001010010110000110000000000101000110111100101011110001011001110010011111110010011011110011110011100100111101111000001000001011011111000101000001010000101111110011101001000100001001010010101110100011011100100111101100100111001100001011100011011010111001111000010000111011011000010001010010111011100011111100110010101100111110010000100110011111001010011111000110001001100001100011100110110100011010000001001011001111110100001100010000110000110110011000011100110100011010111010110110001000011101000100111010101101000011000111011111000100101101010100011000000
Длина последовательности = 1024 

АНАЛИЗ ПОДПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЕЙ

1-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"1" => 0.506 = 259/512 
"0" => 0.494 = 253/512 
2-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"00" => 0.523 = 135/258 "11" => 0.514 = 133/259 
"01" => 0.498 = 126/253 "10" => 0.466 = 118/253 
3-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"111" => 0.564 = 75/133 "100" => 0.533 = 72/135 "010" => 0.520 = 66/127 
"001" => 0.493 = 66/134 "011" => 0.460 = 58/126 "110" => 0.413 = 52/126 
4-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"0010" => 0.603 = 41/68 "0111" => 0.569 = 33/58 "1111" => 0.560 = 42/75 "0100" => 0.541 = 33/61 
"0110" => 0.456 = 31/68 "0011" => 0.455 = 30/66 "1010" => 0.424 = 25/59 "1110" => 0.362 = 21/58 
5-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"10010" => 0.684 = 26/38 "01101" => 0.613 = 19/31 "10000" => 0.606 = 20/33 "11111" => 0.595 = 25/42 "00100" => 0.593 = 16/27 
"00110" => 0.417 = 15/36 "01010" => 0.400 = 14/35 "00011" => 0.375 = 12/32 "10101" => 0.360 = 9/25 "11110" => 0.303 = 10/33 
6-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"010010" => 0.833 = 15/18 "100100" => 0.750 = 9/12 "110111" => 0.750 = 9/12 "101100" => 0.733 = 11/15 "001101" => 0.733 = 11/15 
"010000" => 0.714 = 10/14 
"011000" => 0.316 = 6/19 "011110" => 0.312 = 5/16 "110100" => 0.308 = 4/13 "111110" => 0.294 = 5/17 "000011" => 0.294 = 5/17 
"101001" => 0.235 = 4/17 
7-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"1001001" => 0.889 = 8/9 "0110111" => 0.875 = 7/8 "1010010" => 0.846 = 11/13 "0010000" => 0.833 = 5/6 "0101100" => 0.833 = 5/6 
"0010010" => 0.800 = 4/5 "1010001" => 0.778 = 7/9 
"1010111" => 0.200 = 1/5 "0010001" => 0.200 = 1/5 "1110000" => 0.167 = 1/6 "1000101" => 0.167 = 1/6 "1010101" => 0.125 = 1/8 
"0001010" => 0.000 = 0/7 "1101001" => 0.000 = 0/4 

МАКСИМУМЫ АКФ (из 100):
array (size=10)
  0 => float 1
  92 => float 0.544334975369
  20 => float 0.539408866995
  82 => float 0.534482758621
  85 => float 0.534482758621
  91 => float 0.534482758621
  32 => float 0.527093596059
  94 => float 0.527093596059
  26 => float 0.527093596059
  12 => float 0.524630541872
АВТОРЕГРЕССИЯ ПО ДАРБИНУ

Контроль симметрии матрицы

Точная система (порядок 2):
512.000 f0 + 259.000 f1 = -259.000
259.000 f0 + 512.000 f1 = -251.000
Решение: f = [-0.346550, -0.314929]

Тёплицева система (порядок 2):
511.000 f0 + 259.000 f1 = -259.000
259.000 f0 + 511.000 f1 = -251.000
Решение: f = [-0.347042, -0.315296]

Порядок АР = 100, длина выборки = 1024, СКО выборки = 0.707452):
CKO: 
["001" => 0.609, "002" => 0.582, "003" => 0.561, "004" => 0.550, "005" => 0.545, "006" => 0.538, "007" => 0.534, "008" => 0.529, "009" => 0.521, 
"010" => 0.522, "011" => 0.518, "012" => 0.519, "013" => 0.521, "014" => 0.516, "015" => 0.514, "016" => 0.518, "017" => 0.516, "018" => 0.513, "019" => 0.515, "020" => 0.518, 
"021" => 0.512, "022" => 0.522, "023" => 0.525, "024" => 0.520, "025" => 0.519, "026" => 0.522, "027" => 0.512, "028" => 0.513, "029" => 0.519, "030" => 0.521, "031" => 0.517, 
"032" => 0.518, "033" => 0.518, "034" => 0.520, "035" => 0.517, "036" => 0.526, "037" => 0.522, "038" => 0.513, "039" => 0.519, "040" => 0.521, "041" => 0.515, "042" => 0.524, 
"043" => 0.523, "044" => 0.513, "045" => 0.524, "046" => 0.524, "047" => 0.513, "048" => 0.522, "049" => 0.522, "050" => 0.517, "051" => 0.525, "052" => 0.522, "053" => 0.517, 
"054" => 0.524, "055" => 0.525, "056" => 0.525, "057" => 0.530, "058" => 0.523, "059" => 0.521, "060" => 0.522, "061" => 0.527, "062" => 0.528, "063" => 0.527, "064" => 0.520, 
"065" => 0.522, "066" => 0.528, "067" => 0.525, "068" => 0.522, "069" => 0.528, "070" => 0.525, "071" => 0.526, "072" => 0.532, "073" => 0.532, "074" => 0.521, "075" => 0.529, 
"076" => 0.532, "077" => 0.526, "078" => 0.526, "079" => 0.529, "080" => 0.524, "081" => 0.532, "082" => 0.539, "083" => 0.533, "084" => 0.531, "085" => 0.538, "086" => 0.536, 
"087" => 0.533, "088" => 0.524, "089" => 0.543, "090" => 0.538, "091" => 0.543, "092" => 0.557, "093" => 0.556, "094" => 0.545, "095" => 0.572, "096" => 0.576, "097" => 0.576, 
"098" => 0.603, "099" => 0.610, "100" => 0.598, ]

*** ОКРУГЛЁННЫЙ СИНУС ***

0111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100011100011100011100001110001110001110001111000111000111000111000011100011100011100011110001110001110001110000111000111000111000111100
Длина последовательности = 1024 

АНАЛИЗ ПОДПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЕЙ

1-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"1" => 0.682 = 349/512 
"0" => 0.318 = 163/512 
2-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"01" => 1.000 = 163/163 "11" => 0.533 = 186/349 
"00" => 0.468 = 163/348 "10" => 0.000 = 0/163 
3-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"011" => 1.000 = 163/163 "001" => 1.000 = 162/162 "000" => 0.876 = 163/186 
"100" => 0.000 = 0/162 
4-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"0000" => 1.000 = 24/24 "0011" => 1.000 = 162/162 "0001" => 1.000 = 162/162 "1000" => 0.858 = 139/162 
5-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"00001" => 1.000 = 23/23 "10000" => 1.000 = 23/23 "00011" => 1.000 = 162/162 "10001" => 1.000 = 139/139 "11000" => 0.858 = 139/162 
6-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"100001" => 1.000 = 23/23 "110000" => 1.000 = 23/23 "000011" => 1.000 = 23/23 "110001" => 1.000 = 139/139 "100011" => 1.000 = 139/139 
"111000" => 0.858 = 139/162 
7-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"1110000" => 1.000 = 23/23 "1000011" => 1.000 = 23/23 "1100001" => 1.000 = 23/23 "1111000" => 1.000 = 22/22 "1100011" => 1.000 = 139/139 
"1110001" => 1.000 = 139/139 "0111000" => 0.836 = 117/140 

МАКСИМУМЫ АКФ (из 100):
array (size=10)
  0 => float 1
  44 => float 0.995133819951
  88 => float 0.990267639903
  69 => float 0.963503649635
  25 => float 0.958637469586
  19 => float 0.953771289538
  63 => float 0.948905109489
  94 => float 0.919708029197
  50 => float 0.914841849148
  6 => float 0.9099756691
АВТОРЕГРЕССИЯ ПО ДАРБИНУ

Контроль симметрии матрицы

Точная система (порядок 2):
512.000 f0 + 349.000 f1 = -349.000
349.000 f0 + 512.000 f1 = -186.000
Решение: f = [-0.810685, 0.189315]

Тёплицева система (порядок 2):
511.000 f0 + 349.000 f1 = -349.000
349.000 f0 + 511.000 f1 = -186.000
Решение: f = [-0.814133, 0.192040]

Порядок АР = 100, длина выборки = 1024, СКО выборки = 0.707452):
CKO: 
["001" => 0.408, "002" => 0.696, "003" => 0.896, "004" => 0.748, "005" => 0.468, "006" => 0.331, "007" => 0.600, "008" => 0.824, "009" => 0.928, 
"010" => 0.784, "011" => 0.544, "012" => 0.189, "013" => 0.524, "014" => 0.770, "015" => 0.955, "016" => 0.838, "017" => 0.621, "018" => 0.260, "019" => 0.444, "020" => 0.719, 
"021" => 0.914, "022" => 0.908, "023" => 0.711, "024" => 0.433, "025" => 0.354, "026" => 0.666, "027" => 0.873, "028" => 0.956, "029" => 0.771, "030" => 0.526, "031" => 0.191, 
"032" => 0.595, "033" => 0.820, "034" => 0.993, "035" => 0.828, "036" => 0.606, "037" => 0.222, "038" => 0.514, "039" => 0.763, "040" => 0.949, "041" => 0.881, "042" => 0.677, 
"043" => 0.374, "044" => 0.416, "045" => 0.701, "046" => 0.900, "047" => 0.931, "048" => 0.741, "049" => 0.480, "050" => 0.289, "051" => 0.635, "052" => 0.849, "053" => 0.978, 
"054" => 0.799, "055" => 0.566, "056" => 0.077, "057" => 0.558, "058" => 0.794, "059" => 0.974, "060" => 0.854, "061" => 0.641, "062" => 0.304, "063" => 0.470, "064" => 0.734, 
"065" => 0.926, "066" => 0.905, "067" => 0.708, "068" => 0.428, "069" => 0.360, "070" => 0.670, "071" => 0.876, "072" => 0.954, "073" => 0.768, "074" => 0.522, "075" => 0.202, 
"076" => 0.599, "077" => 0.823, "078" => 0.995, "079" => 0.825, "080" => 0.602, "081" => 0.211, "082" => 0.518, "083" => 0.766, "084" => 0.951, "085" => 0.879, "086" => 0.674, 
"087" => 0.368, "088" => 0.421, "089" => 0.704, "090" => 0.902, "091" => 0.929, "092" => 0.738, "093" => 0.475, "094" => 0.296, "095" => 0.638, "096" => 0.852, "097" => 0.976, 
"098" => 0.796, "099" => 0.562, "100" => 0.046, ]

*** ДАТЧИК mt_rand() ***

1011110010110110011111011001110001010001111001010001000011101000010010011101001111111111001001011010010100110000011001010010000110111011111001110001100010010010110001010001100111010011110010100111111110011111111011000111011101111101100111010110100110001110100010100101110100100010101100111000010110011111111011111100100100011010110010000100101010111110001001111101111000110000001011111100011111110010000101111010010001010010010000111110011111101111110100101010001100100001010101000011000101101001100110101110001001011001101111000001110100100000110100100110001000100100000001100100101000000110111101100000101100001000111010100010001001110101001001101100110101110000100110110010100111001001010011000110111110001100000010000110000110001110110000000111101010000011100000001011110000111110010010001000010000000110011000110011111110001101001101111011101000111011011010110110110110011001100101000000110010101001101111000110101111110011100000110010011000001000001111101111101000000010010011011000111100101000111010111111001101010100
Длина последовательности = 1024 

АНАЛИЗ ПОДПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЕЙ

1-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"1" => 0.514 = 260/506 
"0" => 0.475 = 246/518 
2-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"11" => 0.531 = 138/260 "00" => 0.522 = 142/272 
"01" => 0.498 = 122/245 "10" => 0.419 = 103/246 
3-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"111" => 0.580 = 80/138 "100" => 0.535 = 76/142 "000" => 0.515 = 67/130 
"011" => 0.475 = 58/122 "110" => 0.443 = 54/122 "010" => 0.390 = 48/123 
4-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"0111" => 0.586 = 34/58 "1111" => 0.575 = 46/80 "0001" => 0.561 = 37/66 "0100" => 0.554 = 41/74 
"0010" => 0.420 = 29/69 "0101" => 0.417 = 20/48 "0110" => 0.391 = 25/64 "1010" => 0.352 = 19/54 
5-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"10111" => 0.750 = 18/24 "01110" => 0.667 = 16/24 "01111" => 0.647 = 22/34 "10100" => 0.588 = 20/34 "11000" => 0.576 = 19/33 
"00110" => 0.410 = 16/39 "11110" => 0.382 = 13/34 "00101" => 0.379 = 11/29 "10110" => 0.360 = 9/25 "01010" => 0.286 = 8/28 
6-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"110111" => 0.786 = 11/14 "001111" => 0.750 = 12/16 "110100" => 0.733 = 11/15 "111101" => 0.692 = 9/13 "010111" => 0.667 = 6/9 
"101110" => 0.667 = 4/6 
"101010" => 0.300 = 3/10 "100101" => 0.294 = 5/17 "110110" => 0.286 = 4/14 "001010" => 0.278 = 5/18 "010101" => 0.250 = 2/8 
"011100" => 0.125 = 1/8 
7-битовые предвестники и антагонисты единичного бита:
"0110100" => 1.000 = 5/5 "1101110" => 1.000 = 3/3 "1001111" => 0.889 = 8/9 "0001110" => 0.889 = 8/9 "0110101" => 0.833 = 5/6 
"0000101" => 0.833 = 5/6 "0000000" => 0.833 = 5/6 
"0011100" => 0.167 = 1/6 "1110110" => 0.167 = 1/6 "1000101" => 0.167 = 1/6 "1100101" => 0.125 = 1/8 "1011011" => 0.000 = 0/5 
"1011100" => 0.000 = 0/2 "0111001" => 0.000 = 0/1 

МАКСИМУМЫ АКФ (из 100):
array (size=10)
  0 => float 1
  41 => float 0.543209876543
  24 => float 0.538271604938
  13 => float 0.535802469136
  48 => float 0.525925925926
  58 => float 0.525925925926
  84 => float 0.523456790123
  87 => float 0.523456790123
  42 => float 0.520987654321
  57 => float 0.520987654321
АВТОРЕГРЕССИЯ ПО ДАРБИНУ

Контроль симметрии матрицы

Точная система (порядок 2):
505.000 f0 + 260.000 f1 = -260.000
260.000 f0 + 506.000 f1 = -241.000
Решение: f = [-0.366626, -0.287900]

Тёплицева система (порядок 2):
505.000 f0 + 260.000 f1 = -260.000
260.000 f0 + 505.000 f1 = -241.000
Решение: f = [-0.366226, -0.288675]

Порядок АР = 100, длина выборки = 1024, СКО выборки = 0.703295):
CKO: 
["001" => 0.606, "002" => 0.577, "003" => 0.554, "004" => 0.546, "005" => 0.542, "006" => 0.536, "007" => 0.534, "008" => 0.530, "009" => 0.525, 
"010" => 0.524, "011" => 0.516, "012" => 0.521, "013" => 0.518, "014" => 0.518, "015" => 0.519, "016" => 0.519, "017" => 0.518, "018" => 0.515, "019" => 0.514, "020" => 0.512, 
"021" => 0.509, "022" => 0.508, "023" => 0.513, "024" => 0.518, "025" => 0.512, "026" => 0.512, "027" => 0.519, "028" => 0.517, "029" => 0.513, "030" => 0.513, "031" => 0.511, 
"032" => 0.516, "033" => 0.514, "034" => 0.519, "035" => 0.521, "036" => 0.517, "037" => 0.516, "038" => 0.524, "039" => 0.523, "040" => 0.516, "041" => 0.515, "042" => 0.521, 
"043" => 0.513, "044" => 0.521, "045" => 0.527, "046" => 0.527, "047" => 0.519, "048" => 0.521, "049" => 0.520, "050" => 0.522, "051" => 0.511, "052" => 0.520, "053" => 0.522, 
"054" => 0.511, "055" => 0.521, "056" => 0.529, "057" => 0.520, "058" => 0.515, "059" => 0.520, "060" => 0.521, "061" => 0.520, "062" => 0.524, "063" => 0.526, "064" => 0.514, 
"065" => 0.519, "066" => 0.522, "067" => 0.520, "068" => 0.527, "069" => 0.531, "070" => 0.523, "071" => 0.520, "072" => 0.519, "073" => 0.532, "074" => 0.540, "075" => 0.532, 
"076" => 0.528, "077" => 0.529, "078" => 0.534, "079" => 0.526, "080" => 0.530, "081" => 0.535, "082" => 0.532, "083" => 0.534, "084" => 0.536, "085" => 0.536, "086" => 0.533, 
"087" => 0.531, "088" => 0.530, "089" => 0.529, "090" => 0.527, "091" => 0.537, "092" => 0.530, "093" => 0.531, "094" => 0.530, "095" => 0.537, "096" => 0.529, "097" => 0.532, 
"098" => 0.539, "099" => 0.524, "100" => 0.474, ]
```

Comment: Скорость генерации данных можно узнать? Сколько времени уходит на генерацию килобайта (8192 бит) данных? Я потом вопрос дополню, но есть подозрение на странную зависимость от неизвестно чего. Сейчас генерирую 10 мегабайт данных для нормального запуска теста.

Comment: @Qwertiy Синусный 47 с на 10 Мбит, случайный 88,4 с на 10Мбит

Comment: Не понял, что ты замерял...

Comment: У меня два генератора битовых строк: синусная и случайная. А реальные данные я брал из вопроса

Comment: А я думал, ты моим кодом данные генерировал...